# PHP XLSXWriter - Different Formatting

Tags: php, html, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am using the [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter) code to generate an XLSX file. The file is being generated fine, and it open in Excel fine, but I'm using this file to upload to the DHL server to generate shipping orders. Problem is, their service is complaining about an invalid row. The data in that row is actually perfectly fine, and Excel can read it like I mentioned. However, as a test, what I did was I saved the PHP generated spreadsheet as a separate file, which thus made Microsoft Excel save as it's own format. When I uploaded the Microsoft sheet to the DHL server, it then accepted it without any issues.

After doing a hex compare of the two, they were completely different, which has made me believe that the PHP generated XLSX file is using the OpenOffice or LibreOffice format which DHL hasn't utilised.

Is there any way to fix this issue?
One idea I have is to just ditch the PHP XLSXWriter functionality and just save the data as a raw text file with tab seperated data (which DHL also accepts).

Here is a short example of the primary function in my code:

`$filename = "test.xlsx";
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mysite.com');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.XLSXWriter::sanitize_filename($filename).'"');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');`

```
    $rows = array(
        array('Pick-up Account Number', 'Sales Channel',    'Shipment Order ID',    'Tracking Number',  'Shipping Service Code',    'Company',                      'Consignee Name',                                               'Address Line 1',               'Address Line 2',               'Address Line 3',               'City',                 'State',                        'Postal Code',                  'Destination Country Code',     'Phone Number',         'Email Address',        'Shipment Weight (g)',  'Length (cm)',  'Width (cm)',   'Height (cm)',  'Currency Code',    'Total Declared Value',     'Incoterm', 'Freight',  'Is Insured',   'Insurance',    'Is COD',   'Cash on Delivery Value',   'Recipient ID', 'Recipient ID Type',    'Duties',   'Taxes',    'Workshare Indicator',  'Shipment Description', 'Shipment Import Description',  'Shipment Export Description',  'Shipment Content Indicator',   'Content Description',  'Content Import Description',   'Content Export Description',   'Content Unit Price',   'Content Origin Country',   'Content Quantity', 'Content Weight (g)',   'Content Code', 'HS Code',  'Content Indicator',    'Remarks',  'Shipper Company',  'Shipper Name', 'Shipper Address1', 'Shipper Address2', 'Shipper Address3', 'Shipper City', 'Shipper State',    'Shipper Postal Code',  'Shipper CountryCode',  'Shipper Phone Number', 'Shipper Email address',    'Return Company',   'Return Name',  'Return Address Line 1',    'Return Address Line 2',    'Return Address Line 3',    'Return City',  'Return State', 'Return Postal Code',   'Return Destination Country Code',  'Return Phone Number',  'Return Email Address', 'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3', 'Service4', 'Service5', 'Grouping Reference1',  'Grouping Reference2',  'Customer Reference 1', 'Customer Reference 2',),               
        array('123456789',              '',                 $order_id,              '',                 'PPS',                      $order->shipping_company,       $order->shipping_first_name.' '.$order->shipping_last_name,     $order->shipping_address_1,     $order->shipping_address_2,     $order->shipping_address_3,     $order->shipping_city,  $order->shipping_state,         $order->shipping_postcode,      $order->shipping_country,       $order->billing_phone,  $order->billing_email,  '160',                  '18',           '13',           '6',            'AUD',              '70',                       '',         '',         '',             '',             '',         '',                         '',             '',                     '',         '',         '',                     'Printer Cartridge',    '',                             '',                             '',                             'Printer Cartridge',    '',                             '',                             '70',                   'AU',                       '1',                '',                     'TEST_2214',    '',         '',                     '',         '',                 '',             '',                 '',                 '',                 '',             '',                 '',                     '',                     '',                     '',                         '',                 '',             '',                         '',                         '',                         '',             '',             '',                     '',                                 '',                     '',                     '',         '',         '',         '',         '',         '',                     '',                     '',                     '',),               
    );

    $writer = new XLSXWriter();
    $writer->setAuthor('TEST');

    foreach($rows as $row)
    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row);
    $writer->writeToStdOut();`
```

As a note, the DHL server seemed to be complaining about the data in the row containing 'PPS'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by writing a tab separated file:

```
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.txt");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $rows = array(
    array('Pick-up Account Number', 'Sales Channel',    'Shipment Order ID',    'Tracking Number',  'Shipping Service Code',    'Company',                      'Consignee Name',                                               'Address Line 1',               'Address Line 2',               'Address Line 3',               'City',                 'State',                        'Postal Code',                  'Destination Country Code',     'Phone Number',         'Email Address',        'Shipment Weight (g)',  'Length (cm)',  'Width (cm)',   'Height (cm)',  'Currency Code',    'Total Declared Value',     'Incoterm', 'Freight',  'Is Insured',   'Insurance',    'Is COD',   'Cash on Delivery Value',   'Recipient ID', 'Recipient ID Type',    'Duties',   'Taxes',    'Workshare Indicator',  'Shipment Description', 'Shipment Import Description',  'Shipment Export Description',  'Shipment Content Indicator',   'Content Description',  'Content Import Description',   'Content Export Description',   'Content Unit Price',   'Content Origin Country',   'Content Quantity', 'Content Weight (g)',   'Content Code', 'HS Code',  'Content Indicator',    'Remarks',  'Shipper Company',  'Shipper Name', 'Shipper Address1', 'Shipper Address2', 'Shipper Address3', 'Shipper City', 'Shipper State',    'Shipper Postal Code',  'Shipper CountryCode',  'Shipper Phone Number', 'Shipper Email address',    'Return Company',   'Return Name',  'Return Address Line 1',    'Return Address Line 2',    'Return Address Line 3',    'Return City',  'Return State', 'Return Postal Code',   'Return Destination Country Code',  'Return Phone Number',  'Return Email Address', 'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3', 'Service4', 'Service5', 'Grouping Reference1',  'Grouping Reference2',  'Customer Reference 1', 'Customer Reference 2',),               
    array('123456789',              '',                 $order_id,              '',                 'PPS',                      $order->shipping_company,       $order->shipping_first_name.' '.$order->shipping_last_name,     $order->shipping_address_1,     $order->shipping_address_2,     $order->shipping_address_3,     $order->shipping_city,  $order->shipping_state,         $order->shipping_postcode,      $order->shipping_country,       $order->billing_phone,  $order->billing_email,  '160',                  '18',           '13',           '6',            'AUD',              '70',                       '',         '',         '',             '',             '',         '',                         '',             '',                     '',         '',         '',                     'Printer Cartridge',    '',                             '',                             '',                             'Printer Cartridge',    '',                             '',                             '70',                   'AU',                       '1',                '',                     'TEST_2214',    '',         '',                     '',         '',                 '',             '',                 '',                 '',                 '',             '',                 '',                     '',                     '',                     '',                         '',                 '',             '',                         '',                         '',                         '',             '',             '',                     '',                                 '',                     '',                     '',         '',         '',         '',         '',         '',                     '',                     '',                     '',),               
);

    foreach ($rows as $arr)
    {
       $row = implode("\t", $arr);
       $row.="\n";
       echo $row;
    }
```

This generates the correct data and DHL accepts it. Thanks.